# Yii CMenu active item sometimes sets, sometimes not

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager, cmenu

I have problems to set CMenu active item, sometimes it works, sometimes not.
For my CMenu, "items" array format is:

```
array('label'=>'LED piedāvājumu izstrāde <span class="caret"></span>', 'url'=>array('/customPages/view/id/3', '/rating/index'),'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'dropdown','tabindex'=>"-1"),'linkOptions'=>array('encode'=>false, 'style'=>"width:110px;",'class'=>'dropdown-toggle','data-toggle'=>"dropdown","data-description"=>""), 
                    'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Gaismekļu piemeklēšana', 'url'=>array('/customPages/view/id/3')),
                        array('label'=>'rating', 'url'=>array('/rating/index')),
                    )
```

Item is active `/rating/index`, but not active when link is like `/customPages/view/id/3`

Maybe problem is because of link formatting because in `main.php` in `urlManager` I have a rule `'Gaismeklu_piemeklesana' => 'customPages/view/id/3',`

Someone knows how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your problem that `LED piedav....` is not active, or that the `Gaismekļu piemeklēšana` and `rating` links aren't active? Also the url created for `LED piedav ...` is `/customPages/view/id/3/rating/index`

Comment: Everything is ok if I choose link `'url'=>array('/rating/index'))` - then main item ('LED piedāvājumu izstrāde') is active and also this sublink is active, but if I choose '/customPages/view/id/3' then nothing is active :(

Comment: Respective `'activeCssClass'=>'active',` doesn't work in all cases.